# JavaMail API AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, android, gmail, jakarta-mail

Sorry for my english!
I get a error when I try to send an e-mail from my gmail account, with the JavaMail API in Android.
I get this error: `AuthenticationFailedException`.
I tried following: 
the email address with the password are correct (I tested also with an another mail address).
The settings in google are correct.
I tested with port 465, then I get another exception.
I have searched for 3 days on the internet and have found nothing that has helped.

```
public class MailSending extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private String mail;
private String pass;
private String an;
private String betreff;
private String nachricht;

public MailSending(String mail, String pass, String an, String betreff, String nachricht) {
    this.mail = mail;
    this.pass = pass;
    this.an = an;
    this.betreff = betreff;
    this.nachricht = nachricht;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    final String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session ses = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(mail, pass);
        }
    });

    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(ses);
        InternetAddress addressTo = new InternetAddress(an);
        InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(mail);

        message.setFrom(addressFrom);
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
        message.setSubject(betreff);
        message.setContent(nachricht, "text/plain");

        Transport.send(message);
        Log.d("Nachricht:", "erfolgreich gesendet!");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

> W/System.err: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
>
> W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
>
> W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
>
> W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
>
> W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
>
> W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
>
> W/System.err:     at com.example.tuba.login.MailSending.doInBackground(MailSending.java:72)
>
> W/System.err:     at com.example.tuba.login.MailSending.doInBackground(MailSending.java:25)
>
> W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>
> W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>
> W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>
> W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>
> W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>
> W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Answer (score 1):

Did you find the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail)?

Most likely you need to [enable less secure apps](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmailauth), but without seeing the [details of your exception](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: Thanks.    trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
        connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587.  I get this information, after I add  session.setDebug(true). What mean this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this problem get caused by Gmail account protection. Just click the link below and disable some security settings.

--

Vielleicht wird dieses Problem durch den Gmail-Schutz ausgelöst. Überprüfe deine Sicherheitseinstellungen und deaktiviere einige Einstellungen.

Link: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: I deactivate the security. But this not solved the problem :(

Comment: Are you using 2 Factor-Authorization? If yes I think this can also be the problem because you need to send the code first.

Answer (score 0):

I find a missing parameter from Properties class. Please add the following code and try again.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

According to the documentation:

https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html